# How to shake the page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to prompt the user that something special has happened, so I want to shake the page or blink the whole page. How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: I see you asked a previous question on a slide effect and jQuery was recommended there too. It definitely looks like you need to get to grips with this library. If you cant get it to work, ask a question relating to that.

Comment: Are you sure this functionality won't annoy the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be really easy if you use jQuery for this and you can use `animate` of jQuery to do this.

or you can use jQuery UI Effects to do this!

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake

Comment: any way to do in simple javascript?

Comment: @vakas: not that I know of, more over there might be some compatibility issues, so its better to use a framework like jQuery which takes care of these things internally.

Comment: jquery is just a library of javascript. it is opensource. a few minutes should be enough to get that effect you want if you already know coding in javascript.

Comment: I would use jQuery. Its lightweight, the user doesnt have to install anything, it will save you a lot of hassle. If you want to see how it works, simply step through the code in the library and move it into your own function (but remember to include the notice from the jQuery file)